# If data is null, dont show

Tags: javascript, xml

This is my code. I get the data from xml. What I want is:
if a piece of data is null, don't show that row. How can I do it?

```
 downloadUrl("xml/cat.xml", function(doc) {
     var xml = xmlParse(doc);
     var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");   

     for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
         // obtain the attribues of each marker
         var lat = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat"));
         var lng = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng"));
         var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
         var kWa = markers[i].getAttribute("kWa");     

         var html = 'rows here  ';
```

Sorry for wrong question..

i want to hide here

```
var html = '

id='+id+', kwa='+kwa+' // if id is null how can hide item in here..?  

';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `if` checks like:

```
 if(markers[i].getAttribute("lat") != NULL) // or "NULL" as a string if thats what is returned."
     var lat = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat));
```

Or you could put it in a `try - catch` statement:

```
for (//codes){
    try{ 
        //try parsing here
    }catch(e){
        if(e) // do something with the error
}
```

Which has the advantage of letting you do something for each error message. But the disadvantage of being slow. (though not as slow as it used to be in javascript)